# "FltStartFiltering has not been called" Error of trying to attach a volume in DriverEntry

Tags: winapi, driver, minifilter, filefilter, filter-driver

I have tried to attach a volume while the driver service starts, but I got "**The filter is not ready for attachment to volumes because it has not finished initialize (FltStartFiltering has not been called).**" and immediately I got blue screen. I have already called the **FltStartFiltering** but I don't know why it didn't work.

Below is my code:

```
status = FltRegisterFilter(DriverObject,
        &FilterRegistration,
        &MiniSpyData.Filter);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {

        leave;
    }




    status = FltBuildDefaultSecurityDescriptor(&sd,
        FLT_PORT_ALL_ACCESS);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        leave;
    }

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&uniString, WOODY_PORT_NAME);

    InitializeObjectAttributes(&oa,
        &uniString,
        OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE | OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE,
        NULL,
        sd);

    status = FltCreateCommunicationPort(MiniSpyData.Filter,
        &MiniSpyData.ServerPort,
        &oa,
        NULL,
        SpyConnect,
        SpyDisconnect,
        SpyMessage,
        1);

    FltFreeSecurityDescriptor(sd);



    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        leave;
    }

    //
    //  We are now ready to start filtering
    //

    status = FltStartFiltering(MiniSpyData.Filter);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {

        FltUnregisterFilter(MiniSpyData.Filter);
    }
    else {
     //Here is what I want to attach
        RtlInitUnicodeString(&uniString, L"\\Device\\HarddiskVolume1");
        PFLT_VOLUME vol;
        FltGetVolumeFromName(&MiniSpyData.Filter, &uniString, &vol);
        status = FltAttachVolume(&MiniSpyData.Filter, vol, NULL, NULL);
    }
```

Comment: in call `FltGetVolumeFromName` and `FltAttachVolume` must be not  `&MiniSpyData.Filter` but `MiniSpyData.Filter` - this if fatal error. also as general note - for what you call `FltAttachVolume` ? fltmgr auto attach your filter to existing volumes

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's my mistake. Now it works... The filter driver won't attach if I restart PC. I checked the service and it is running surely...

Comment: Unless I  call FltAttachVolume() ... But if I call FltAttachVolume() in the DriverEntry, it could attach once service load, but after few seconds got blue screen again.. I need to check the code again... Thanks for your help

Comment: *The filter driver won't attach* must auto attach, only if it not xp/2000. [*The filter manager automatically notifies a minifilter driver about an available volume by calling its InstanceSetupCallback routine on the first create operation after the volume is mounted.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/loading-and-unloading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RtlInitUnicodeString(&uniString, L"\\Device\\HarddiskVolume1");
PFLT_VOLUME vol;
FltGetVolumeFromName(&MiniSpyData.Filter, &uniString, &vol);
status = FltAttachVolume(&MiniSpyData.Filter, vol, NULL, NULL);
```

The part above is simply not needed and wrong as well.
Let me explain:

1. The **FltGetVolumeFromName** routine take a PFLT_FILTER as the first parameter and from what I see in your code you are giving it a PFLT_FILTER*
2. You don't need to manually attach to volumes since you will automatically attach and be called in your instance context unless you set the **FLTFL_INSTANCE_SETUP_MANUAL_ATTACHMENT** in your instance context registration flags. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/fltkernel/nc-fltkernel-pflt_instance_setup_callback) for more details.
3. You don't want to do this during boot because the volume might not be there yet and thus your potential BSOD.

Good luck.